# Azure DevOps pipelines CI trigger not invoking when a commit is made to 'other git' repo

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I’m attempting to configure Azure DevOps pipelines for continuous integration (CI) but when I commit a change into a specified target branch and push it to the remote origin (other Git) it is failing to trigger the pipeline build.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers, it's possible to select the pipeline CI triggers even if your source code is in a remote Git repo or Subversion because when using this trigger, it will mean that azure pipelines polls for changes at a regular interval.

Based on this information below is how i configured the CI trigger in Azure Devops

[image]

Bitbucket is our Git repository management solution which is self-hosted (not cloud), it is available on a public domain but requires authentication (username & password) to access the repository. As far as I am aware there is no firewall blocking the connection which I’ve read can block the connection.

In project settings in Azure Devops I have added a ‘new service connection’ of the type ‘other Git’ and specified the following settings (removed real values). With this service connection configured it is also configured to get sources.

[image]

[image]

If I trigger the pipeline build manually or set it to schedule there are no issues with it kicking off. I have tried playing around with different settings i.e. permissions it the portal but whatever I have tried I have not been able to push to the master branch and it trigger a build automatically.

Is this possible to achieve or am I missing something obvious? During my searching for a solution i have read about web hook, perhaps this is required?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please add new service connection from the pipeline and have another try:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have removed my service connections and recreated multiple time and it has not resolved the issue. I have also tried using other types of service connections. Its worth noting that for the git repo URL ive tried the clone url with the username and without e.g. https://myuser@mydomain/path/path/my-website.git & https://mydomain/path/path/my-website.git. No luck. I have tried creating it from the location you specified and still no change.

Comment: From the test on my side, if adding new service connection from the pipeline as the screenshot shows, the CI will be triggered. But if creating the service connection from `service connections`, the CI won't be triggered.

Comment: which 'other git' platform are you using to test please? This still remains an issue and i'm now exploring the option of importing the source code into repos.

Comment: I've tested with bitbucket.org.

Comment: Ended up moving the source code into Azure Repos. We can now use triggers. Thanks for the help